# CakePHP retrieve document

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I've a file named `test.txt` in `app/webroot/files/filecache/` directory.

Now, I want to show this file within [this viewer](http://www.accusoft.com/cloudconnectapi.htm) using `iframe`. but I can't get the `url` to that file correctly.

I've tried:

`$uurl = $this->Html->url('/files/filecache/test.txt' , true);`

in `ctp` file.

How can i get that url correctly?

Comment: That looks fine to me. What is it doing?

Answer (score 0):

If you echo $uurl and copy + paste what it echo's into your browser, does the file load?

You may have the permissions on your files/filecache folder set incorrectly, preventing files from being viewed by visitors.

Paste the output of $uurl directly into the browser to see the error that will allow you to debug.